The golden ratio $\phi$ for $_2F_1\big(\frac16,\frac16,\frac23,-2^7\phi^9\big)$ and $_2F_1\big(\frac16,\frac56,1,\frac{\phi^{-5}}{5\sqrt5}\big)$?
I. Context
Given the golden ratio $\phi$, then we have the nice closed-forms,
\begin{align}
_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac16,\frac23,-2^7\phi^9\right) &= \frac{3}{5^{5/6}}\phi^{-1}\\[6pt]
_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac56,1,\,\frac{\phi^{-5}}{5\sqrt5}\right)\, &= \left(\frac{3\sqrt3}{8}\right)^{1/3}\left(\frac{5\sqrt5}{4}\right)^{1/6}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)^3}{2\pi^2}
\end{align}
The fact that the  $_2F_1\big(a,b;c;z\big)$ have simple relations between their $(a,b,c)$, the parameter $z$ involves the same constant, and they have closed-forms is suggestive they have a connection.
In fact, given the j-function $j(\tau)$, the $z_k$ were derived similarly.
\begin{align}
\frac{j(\tau_1)}{1728} &= 4z_1(1-z_1)\\[4pt]
\frac{j(\tau_2)}{1728} &= \frac1{4z_2(1-z_2)}
\end{align}
The parameter $z_1$ was discussed in an old MSE post, while $z_2$ (the case $s=\frac16$) was moved from a new MO post as it was getting too long. Let $j = j(\tau)$ and $\delta = z_2,$ so,
$$\delta =z_2= \frac12\Big(1\color{red}-\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1728}j}\Big)$$
Then the proposed $24$th power formula,
$$j(\tau) \overset{\color{red}?}= \left(\frac{\sqrt{_2F_1\big(\tfrac16,\tfrac56,1,\delta\big)}}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{24}$$
seems true for $\tau = \sqrt{-d}\,$ if integer $d>0,$ and for $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}2\,$ if integer $d>3.$ Note that the modular discriminant $\Delta(\tau) = \big(\eta(\tau)\sqrt{2\pi}\big)^{24}$ also involves a $24$th power.
So when exact values for $j(\tau)$ and $\eta(\tau)$ are known, then it is simple manipulation to get explicit evaluations of the $_2F_1$ as in the examples below.

II. Examples

Let $\tau = \sqrt{-3}$, so $j=j(\tau)=2\times30^3$. We have the one from the title,
$$_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac56,1,\,\frac{\phi^{-5}}{5\sqrt5}\right) = \left(\frac{3\sqrt3}{8}\right)^{1/3}\left(\frac{5\sqrt5}{4}\right)^{1/6}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac13\big)^3}{2\pi^2}$$
Let $\tau = \sqrt{-7}$, so $j=j(\tau)=255^3$. Then,
$$_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac56,1,\tfrac12\Big(1-\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1728}{255^3}}\Big)\right) = \left(\frac{255}7\right)^{1/4}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac17\big) \Gamma\big(\frac27\big) \Gamma\big(\frac47\big)}{2\times(2\pi)^2\;}$$
Let $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}2$, so $j=j(\tau)=-15^3$. Then,
$$_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac56,1,\tfrac12\Big(1-\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1728}{-15^3}}\Big)\right) = \left(\frac{15}7\right)^{1/4}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac17\big) \Gamma\big(\frac27\big) \Gamma\big(\frac47\big)}{(2\pi)^2}$$
Let $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}2$, so $j=j(\tau)=-32^3$. Then,

$$_2F_1\left(\frac16,\frac56,1,\tfrac12\Big(1-\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1728}{-32^3}}\Big)\right) = \left(\frac{32}{11}\right)^{1/4}\,\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac1{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac3{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac4{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac5{11}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac9{11}\big)}{(2\pi)^3}$$
and so on for other $\tau$.

III. Question
Q: So is the proposed $24$th power formula for $j(\tau)$ above in fact true?
